# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null exception

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot. I have a rest api GET call that I need to send the body using raw,and headers. I can hit this url from postman reponse is came . But when I try to call this from Java side I'm getting a 400 null exception.

Below is what I tried in Java.

```
String requestObject="{\"processUuid\":\"5f11d399b592ef00010fb87a\"}";
         JsonObject properties = new JsonObject();
           properties.addProperty("processUuid", (String) dataMap.get("processUuid"));
           HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(properties.toString(), headers);
           ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,
                entity,Map.class);
      if (responseEntity != null) {
            Map<String, Object> data = responseEntity.getBody();
            List<Map> list = (List<Map>) data.get("resultObject");
            Map<String, Object> map = list.get(0);
            qcTaskName = (String) map.get("actName");

        }
```

I'm getting this exception.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `requestObject`?

Comment: What is `headers`?

Comment: iam giving requestBody json that json convert string put into requestObject

Comment: headers means iam seting 2 paramters  authriozation and id

Comment: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.set("tenantId", "client_2");
   headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, accessToken);;

Comment: Yes, you assign a string literal to `requestObject` and then you *never use* the variable, so what's the point? --- Since we don't know what a good request looks like, how did you expect us to be able to help?

Comment: I suggest you to use Rest clients to reduce good amount of boilerplate coding. Try Unirest http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#requests